# How to change text size in QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt

Hello I want to make text font smaller with QGraphicsScene. I try this:

```
QFont * f = new QFont;
f->setPointSize(7);
tt->setFont(f);
```

However, I get this:

> error: C2664: 'void QGraphicsTextItem::setFont(const QFont &)' :
>   cannot convert argument 1 from 'QFont *' to 'const QFont &' Reason:
>   cannot convert from 'QFont *' to 'const QFont' No constructor could
>   take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

Can you help me?

Comment: Prefer values. If you write `new` in modern C++, you better had a good reason for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to derefence the pointer to get the object. Then `setFont` can work with this object:

```
tt->setFont(*f);
```

Remember to explicitly `delete` `f`. If you have access to C++11 I'd recommend using `std::unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer with `new`.

Better yet, if you don't need to use `f` outside of the scope then just create a local object :

```
QFont f;
f->setPointSize(7);
tt->setFont(f);
```

Comment: `QFont` is a value class with cheap copies. If you're allocating it on the heap, you're most likely doing something wrong and scope got nothing to do with it.